# Referencing in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, nosql

Sorry but I'm so newbie to MongoDB and Spring-data and i have a question about these two classes :

```
@Document(collection = "person")
public class Person  {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6268875544266598239L;
    @Id
    private String Id;
    private String name;

    //@DBRef(db = "mail")
    ArrayList<Mail> mails = new ArrayList<Mail>();
```

and the other one is :

```
@Document(collection = "mail")
public class Mail  {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9149555841222037638L;
    @Id
    private String Id;
    private String mail;

    Person person;
```

Will I have a problem in referencing in this case ? I mean do i need to put `@DBref` or `@Reference` or any other annotation to work as for the `@ManyToOne` annotation in `JPA`? I saw many exemples but i cant get the point does it work without any annotation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without annotation it will save `mail` objects inline in the `person` documents. Viceversa with the annotation it will save the `mail` [DBRefs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#dbrefs) in the `person` documents.

Example:

- `person` document without `@DBRef` in: `{"id":"foo", "name":"bar", "mails":[{"id":"abc", "mail":"hello"},{"id":"def","mail":"world"}]}`
- `person` document with `@DBRef`: `{"id":"foo", "name":"bar", "mails":[{"$ref":"mail","$id":"abc"},{"$ref":"mail","$id":"def"}]}`

This means that if you need consistency between the `person` and the `mail` collections you should use `@DBRef`, in this case its behaviour is like a `@OneToMany` annotation in JPA context.

**But** if you need a relation between two documents in the 99% of the cases you need a relational dbms instead of mongo.